# Получить доступ не к глобальной временной таблице

Tags: sql-server

Есть локальные временные таблицы(#) и глобальные(##).

Обе создаются физически в tempdb и различаются видимостью.

Вопрос вот в чем:

Если я точно знаю, что где-то в данный момент существует локальная временная таблица, но не в моей сессии, я как-нибудь могу ее прочитать?

Answer (score 2):

Можете, но только с правами админа и с определенными сложностями.
Проблема с локальными temp таблицами в следующем. Данные из них может напрямую запрашивать только владелец, то есть кто их создал в своей сессии. В самой **TempDB** таблица `#mytemp` будет создана как `#mytemp_____00000090019545666` и видна прочим пользователям именно так.
Чтобы прочитать данные из нее - примерные действия:

Получить object id;

```
select object_id from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '#mytemp%'
```

Получить список страниц

```
dbcc ind('tempdb', <object id>, -1)
```

Для каждой PageFID / PagePID (file/page IDs)

```
dbcc traceon(3604);
dbcc page(tempdb, <PageFID>, <PagePID>, 3) with tableresults
```